# Pass Parameters to SharePoint 2013 Timer Job

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, timer-jobs

I would like to run a timer job with parameters from the UI. But how can I pass parameters from the UI if I can only press "Run now" in Timer Job Monitoring? Or where can I pass them?

I can not find any possibility to insert a string or number to pass a parameter via the SharePoint Website UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know its not possible pass parameter from UI. You can store the value some where like in the list and then read it in timer job.

Comment: I will try it like this. Thanks :)